# Transpose data in R by IDnumber

Tags: r, reshape

I have a question of transposing data in R. Basically I am looking for an alternative to do proc transpose by id prefix = test and proc transpose by id prefix = score in R.
So I have a set of data looks like the following

```
ID  test date   score
1   4/1/2001    98
1   5/9/2001    65
1   5/23/2001   85
2   3/21/2001   76
2   4/8/2001    58
2   5/22/2001   67
2   6/15/2001   53
3   1/15/2001   46
3   5/30/2001   55
4   1/8/2001    71
4   2/14/2001   95
4   7/15/2001   93
```

and I would love to transpose it into:

```
id  test date1  score1  test date2  score2  testdate3   score3  testdate4   score4
1   4/1/2000    98      5/9/2001    65      5/23/2001   85  .   
2   3/21/2001   76      4/8/2001    58      5/22/2001   67      6/15/2001   53
3   1/15/2001   46      5/30/2001   55      .       .   
4   1/8/2001    71      2/14/2001   95      7/15/2001   93  .
```

Comment: Check out the reshape2 library, specifically functions `cast` and `melt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic "long" to "wide" reshaping task. In base R, you can use `reshape`, but only after adding a "time" variable, like this:

```
mydf$time <- with(mydf, ave(ID, ID, FUN = seq_along))
reshape(mydf, direction = "wide", idvar = "ID", timevar = "time")
#    ID test.date.1 score.1 test.date.2 score.2 test.date.3 score.3
# 1   1    4/1/2001      98    5/9/2001      65   5/23/2001      85
# 4   2   3/21/2001      76    4/8/2001      58   5/22/2001      67
# 8   3   1/15/2001      46   5/30/2001      55        <NA>      NA
# 10  4    1/8/2001      71   2/14/2001      95   7/15/2001      93
#    test.date.4 score.4
# 1         <NA>      NA
# 4    6/15/2001      53
# 8         <NA>      NA
# 10        <NA>      NA
```